# Swift Timer error when function has arguments

Tags: swift, nstimer

I'm trying to make a function that activates every one second, which adds 1 to a variable (`texttimer`) and adds a letter to a string (`typedStory`), which is displayed on a label (`storyLabel`).

Everything worked fine until I added an argument (`finalStory`) to the function. Now I'm getting an an error:

> -[__NSCFTimer substringToIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Here's the code I have:

```
func textTypeWelcome(finalStory: NSString){
    var newTimer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.05, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.textTypeWelcome), userInfo: finalStory, repeats: false)
    texttimer += 1
    typedStory = finalStory.substring(to: texttimer)
    storyLabel.text = typedStory

}
```

The code works, however doesn't do what I want if I remove the argument and put `userInfo` to nil.

Anyone know of a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that cannot work, the action method takes the **timer** as parameter – what the error message tells you – and you get `finalStory` from the `userInfo` parameter.

```
func textTypeWelcome(timer: Timer) {
    let finalStory = timer.userInfo as! String
    var newTimer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.05, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.textTypeWelcome), userInfo: finalStory, repeats: false)
    texttimer += 1
    typedStory = finalStory.substring(to: texttimer)
    storyLabel.text = typedStory
}
```

Try this out in a Playground

```
class Foo  : NSObject {

    let string = "Hello World"
    var counter = 1

    var typedStory = ""

    var timer = Timer()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerFired), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        print("timer started")
    }

    func timerFired(timer : Timer) {

        typedStory = string.substring(to: string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: counter))
        print(typedStory)
        if typedStory == string {
            timer.invalidate()
            print("timer stopped")
        } else {
            counter += 1
        }
    }
}

let foo = Foo()
```

You have to add the lines

```
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

to allow asynchronous API

Comment: So I added that function but now I'm confused when I use textTypeWelcome, where do I put the string that has finalStory? Also finalStory needs to be an NSString to be able to get the substring, how would you recommend I do that? (I'm still learning swift) Thanks!

Comment: Honestly I'm confused about the entire method. I have no idea what you are going to accomplish. My answer is just for solving the error.

Comment: I'm trying to make an app that gives you a scenario and you have to select which choice you will make. The point the the method is theres a string that has the story and on the app the letters will appear one at a time, like someone is typing it. I want to be able to say like textTypeWelcome("What would you do if bla bla bla") and it would look like someone is typing on the the screen I just don't know where I would put the string when I'm calling the method.

Comment: Clever, but I would discourage this. You're essentially manually creating your own closure (a function + captured state). There are variants of `scheduledTimer` that take a closure, directly.